# Searching local MQTT server on Local network

Tags: mqtt

I have a micro-controller,ESP8266 for the moment, which is connecting to a mqtt broker and pulish some messages.
I have configured mqtt broker on raspberry pi which has an IP address `192.168.43.164`.
so for now I have hard coded the mqtt broker IP in micro-controller firmware. But I want it like it search the mqtt server in local network and then connect to the same.

so is it possible to do the same ?? Does such micro-controller can have that capability to do so?
I have already search a lot on Google but does not found any solution. Please provide some path.

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct response to this is DNS with different versions for LAN and public Internet.

For finding devices on the local network you want to use the [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS#Resource_Records) (also known as Avahi or Bonjour) and you want to publish your broker using the `_mqtt._tcp` service.

Setting up Avahi on the Raspberry pi to publish the service is relatively [simple](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/master/avahi-daemon/example.service), and there are mDNS libraries for Arduino to do the lookup.

Likewise for finding a public MQTT broker on the Internet for a given organisation they should publish their broker details using a [service record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) (SRV) e.g. example.com would publish the SRV record at `_mqtt._tcp.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Although I have accepted @hardillb answer. But I am writing this answer to share the another approach that I came across when researching around this.

Ok so idea is to use IP Broadcasting. So what I have done is, my edge device is continuously emitting an UDP messages over broadcast IP that contains the itself IP. The micro-controller ESP listen to UDP messages and extract IP from that and connect to it.

So advantage is that if I have more then one edge device is in system, it is easy to allocate different edge to UC at run time.That keeps the load balancing too.

Thanks